# If $u\in\omega^*$, is it possible that $u^{\omega_1}$ is an ultrafilter on $\omega^{\omega_1}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Let $u\in\omega^*$ be a free ultrafilter on $\omega$.

Let $u^{\omega_{1}}=\{\prod_{\alpha\in\omega_{1}}A_{\alpha}:A_\alpha\in u $ for each $ \alpha\in\omega_1\}$.

Is it possible that $u^{\omega_{1}}$ is an ultrafilter on the set $\omega^{\omega_1}$?

You may assume GCH, if that matters.

Thank you

Comment: Generally $\omega^*$ often denotes the order type of the negative integers. What does it mean here?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $\omega^*=\beta\omega\setminus \omega$ - it's just another way of saying $u$ is a free ultrafilter on $\omega$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place, your $u^{\omega_1}$ is not even a filter, because it is not closed upwards. I think you meant to ask whether the filter on $\omega^{\omega_1}$, for which $u^{\omega_1}$ is a base, is an ultrafilter. The answer is no, because neither the set $\{f\in\omega^{\omega_1}:f(0)\lt f(1)\}$ nor its complement $\{f\in\omega^{\omega_1}:f(0)\ge f(1)\}$ belongs to the filter.